# How to completely purge all references to Intel graphics drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, package-management, graphics, intel-graphics

I have added an nVidia graphics card, and now I can't get completely rid of Intel integrated drivers. Attempting to remove them requires removal of huge number of packages, some of them quite essential (such as Qt5). Is there a way to resolve this without resorting to complete OS reinstall?

List of remaining Intel packages:

```
dzenan@corista:/etc/apt$ dpkg --get-selections | grep intel
libdrm-intel1:amd64             install
libdrm-intel1:i386              install
```

Trying to install a package involving OpenGL:

```
dzenan@corista:/etc/apt$ sudo apt install libcairo2-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcairo2-dev : Depends: libcairo2 (= 1.14.6-1) but 1.15.2-0intel1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**How to remove information about the intel version of this and other packages from the package management system? Intel offers their own version of a lot of graphics-related packages.**

aptitude's suggestion shows package statistics:

```
dzenan@corista:/etc/apt$ sudo aptitude remove libdrm-intel1 
The following packages will be REMOVED:  
  fonts-ancient-scripts{u} libdrm-intel1 ttf-ancient-fonts{u} 
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 27.3 MB will be freed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-dri : Depends: libdrm-intel1 (>= 2.4.48) but it is not going to be installed.
 i965-va-driver : Depends: libdrm-intel1 (>= 2.4.46) but it is not going to be installed.
 libdrm-dev : Depends: libdrm-intel1 (= 2.4.67-1ubuntu0.16.04.2) but it is not going to be installed.
open: 249; closed: 3547; defer: 178; conflict: 457
...and a list of 618 packages
```

apt's list is shorter:

```
dzenan@corista:/etc/apt$ sudo apt remove libdrm-intel1 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcontent-hub0 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                            libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libkf5waylandclient5 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                                 libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
 liboxideqt-qmlplugin : Depends: libqt5quick5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                                 libqt5quick5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
 liboxideqtcore0 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.4.0) but it is not going to be installed or
                            libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
 liboxideqtquick0 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                             libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libqt5quick5 (>= 5.2.0) but it is not going to be installed or
                             libqt5quick5-gles (>= 5.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
 libqmenumodel0 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                           libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt5multimedia5 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.2.0) but it is not going to be installed or
                              libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt5multimediaquick-p5 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                                     libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libqt5quick5 (>= 5.4.0) but it is not going to be installed or
                                     libqt5quick5-gles (>= 5.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt5waylandclient5 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.5.0) but it is not going to be installed or
                                 libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.5.0) but it is not going to be installed
 libthumbnailer-qt1.0 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                                 libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libubuntugestures5 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                               libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libqt5quick5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                               libqt5quick5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libubuntutoolkit5 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                              libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
 qml-module-io-thp-pyotherside : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                                          libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
                                 Depends: libqt5quick5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                                          libqt5quick5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
 qml-module-qtpositioning : Depends: libqt5quick5 (>= 5.2.0~beta1) but it is not going to be installed or
                                     libqt5quick5-gles (>= 5.2.0~beta1) but it is not going to be installed
 qml-module-ubuntu-layouts : Depends: libqt5quick5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                                      libqt5quick5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
 qml-module-ubuntu-thumbnailer0.1 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                                             libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
                                    Depends: libqt5quick5 (>= 5.5.0) but it is not going to be installed or
                                             libqt5quick5-gles (>= 5.5.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```